# Writing MacPaint files?

Tags: macos, classic-mac-os

What current Mac utility or paint program (something that will run directly on Snow Leopard or Lion, not requiring an emulator), if any, can write valid MacPaint files (readable by MacPaint 1.x on a 512Ke)?

Assume I have access to a disk drive with which I can copy files to an 800K Mac formatted diskette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GraphicConverter](http://lemkesoft.com/) can handle this format (and just about every other bitmap image format). When saving the image, you need to select "show all" from the file-format popup menu in the save dialog in order to reveal this format as an option.